# Wordpress plugin suggest not working properly

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, themes, wordpress-theming

I am a WordPress developer and recently i created a magazine theme. In my theme, I used some (wordpress.org) plugins for my customer giving extra benefits. And after theme installation, my theme auto-suggest the plugins to install & for this, I have used tgm plugin (http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) for auto theme suggest.

i integrated that in my theme & it shows suggestion message on the dashboard for install that plugins. but the main problem is when I going to Appearance >> Install plugins. Plugins name shows perfectly and also its successfully install those plugins but under plugins name >> Show install button and also show a big link.

as we know, there will have only install button then clients will click on install button and install the themes. I tried many times for solve this problem. I am using the latest version of tgm plugin. & also I tried to solve this problem with old versions & its shows same result. For your kind information here's the **Screenshot of this issue**.

[image]
Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo .. i Solved this ,, actually i find out in that website, it was a bug but when i downloaded that plugin from github its finally solved automatically, that's mean plugin author updated and fixed the bug in github. i share this for newcomers, if anyone faced this problem, just download latest version from github (https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation)

[Screenshot for solve the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu6Xw.png)

Thanks.